# postfix - act as a relay but don't deliver

Tags: postfix, email-server

I would like my postfix server to act as a relay/smarthost for some clients, but would like to deliver all mail to a local (Maildir-style) mailbox instead of sending on to the intended recipient. Sounds a bit weird, I know, but it is intended for testing purposes on our test environments.

For our live environment, I would like to deliver mail normally.

My current `main.cf` looks like this:

```
myhostname = mymail.mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.5.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 192.168.5.43, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

default_process_limit = 100
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 10
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 30
queue_minfree = 20971520
header_size_limit = 51200
message_size_limit = 10485760
smtpd_recipient_limit = 100

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.crt 
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mailcert.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
```

/etc/postfix/mydestinations:

```
/^mymail.mydomain.com$/          ACCEPT
/^localhost.localdomain$/           ACCEPT
/^localhost$/                       ACCEPT
/^.*\.mydomain\.com$/       ACCEPT
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
@mydomain.com catchall
```

I've been told this is possible, but can't really find any specific info as to how to achieve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone showed me a config that worked:

(abbreviated) /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost, $myhostname


relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.5.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 192.168.5.43, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = all

recipient_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map
```

/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical_map:

```
/./  catchall
```

This leads to the desired outcome for mail delivery:

Dec  1 09:40:42 mailserver postfix/qmgr[7943]: 58242139670: from=, size=703, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  1 09:40:42 mail-it-int postfix/smtpd[7944]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.5.2] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Dec  1 09:40:42 mail-it-int postfix/local[7949]: 58242139670: to=, orig_to=, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)

...and the mail intended to be routed externally is diverted to a local mailbox

Answer (score 1):

I see two different problems with your current configuration:

- Your domains are in [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) while you are trying to implement your catch-all address using [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps), which would require the domains to be in [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains).
- You only have `@example.com` in your `virtual_alias_maps`, while the regular expression `^.*\.example\.com$/` suggests you would need this catch-all for every `*.example.com`. In order to do that you'd need to be able to use regular expression on your `virtual`, too. Since this is not possible with `hash:`, you'd need to use `pcre:` here, too.

You need to modify these settings in your `main.cf`:

```
mydestination = localhost
virtual_alias_domain = pcre:/etc/postfix/mydestinations
virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And your `/etc/postfix/virtual` would have this regular expression:

```
/@((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+example\.com/ catchall
```

If you use `pcre:` make sure that your Postfix is built with the [PCRE support](http://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html). You also have an option to use `regexp:`, instead, but you won't be able to use the Perl style regular expressions. See [Postfix Lookup Table Overview](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html):

> **pcre** (read-only)
>
> A lookup table based on Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. The file
>   format is described in [pcre_table(5)](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html). The lookup table name as used in
>   `pcre:table` is the name of the regular expression file.
>
> **regexp** (read-only)
>
> A lookup table based on regular expressions. The file format is
>   described in [regexp_table(5](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html)). The lookup table name as used in
>   `regexp:table` is the name of the regular expression file.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, it turns out I'm asking the wrong question, though :) I've posted a follow-up here: https://serverfault.com/questions/885483/postfix-catchall-user-not-found-in-virtual-alias-table