# postfix catchall user not found in virtual alias table

Tags: postfix, email-server

My task is to create a postfix config that accepts all mail from all domains, recipients, etc. and forwards them to a catchall mailbox. This may be further filtered in future and indeed the config will need to be latered in another environment so that mail goes through to the intended recipient.

Here's an abbreviated main.cf:

```
....
myhostname = mailserver.fqdn
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination =
myorigin = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.5.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = 192.168.5.43, 127.0.0.1
inet_protocols = all

virtual_alias_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_minimum_uid = 2222
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:2222
virtual_gid_maps = static:2222
....
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
/.*/     catchall
/catchall\@localhost/ catchall
```

Other machines are configured to use this mail server as a relayhost, and when mail makes it to here, this appears in the log:

```
Nov 28 10:08:10 mailserver.fqdn postfix/error[23768]: 5EA9BBD9F5: to=<catchall@localhost>, orig_to=<root@mailsender.fqdn>, relay=none, delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (User unknown in virtual alias table)
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, is it the presence of `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases`?

Also, if all goes well, can I expect the catchall mailbox to be created automatically, or is there another config item needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the outcome with `postmap -q "something@example.com" pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual`. It should return `catchall`. What may happen here is that the `/.*/  catchall` also includes the `catchall@localhost`, making it to loop back to itself and eventually not resolved to any real user.

If you only have a certain domain and its subdomains, it would be more safe to use:

```
/@((\w[\w\-]*)\.)+example\.com/ catchall
```

Then, handle the localhost with `$local_transport` mail delivery transport using

```
mydestination = localhost
```

Now, your `catchall@localhost` may be a real local user or an alias defined in `/etc/aliases`.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to relay the mail, which is actually what I don't want. I'd like the "catchall" user to receive all mail. For testing, I created a UNIX user "joeschmo" and added `catchall:       joeschmo` to `/etc/aliases` and ran `newaliases`

Comment: Gah! It seems I had a correct configuration a few hours ago, but didn't realise and have since changed it! There are lines like `Nov 28 14:50:56 mailserver.fqdn postfix/local[9353]: B36F4BD8F4: to=<joeschmo@localhost>, orig_to=<external-address@gmail.com>, relay=local, delay=0.01, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)`. Very frustrating!

Comment: The above answer is correct, but for a solution to the requirements stated in the first paragraph, I answered my own original question here: https://serverfault.com/a/886114/87359, if anyone's interested

Answer (score 0):

Just editing the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file is not enough to make the changes take affect. You must run the `postmap` command to make `postfix` read the file, like so:

```
/usr/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

This creates a new file called `/etc/postfix/virtual.db` and the aliases are now loaded into `postfix`.

Comment: Sorry - I should have stated that I'd already done this, and tested using `postmap -q ...`

Comment: Also, this is not the typical `hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` that needs the `.db` file, but a [pcre table](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html), `pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual`.